# "Move comments to chat" has stopped deleting the comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

The move comments to chat option doesn't delete the comments, even when I select the "Also delete the moved comments from the post" button. ([Have tried it multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao?tab=activity&sort=comments)).

This seems to be happening since yesterday, and was alright till at least Monday last week.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1333/discussion-on-question-by-bhargav-rao-move-comments-to-chat-has-stopped-deleti).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry about that; should be fixed now.

The reward for your patience: this action now completes without refreshing the page; deleted comments will be reloaded inline.